# How to make div sticky to the right and to the left at the same time while scrolling

Tags: html, css

You can horizontal scroll and see that "Second part" div is sticky to the right but not sticky to the left.
I need it to be sticky to the left as well as it's sticked to the right.

Please see the code below.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#first-part {
  left: 105px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#second-part {
  position: sticky;
  left: 105px; /*doesn't work*/
  right: 105px; /*works*/
  width: 130px; 
  background-color: silver;
}
.text-in-second-part {
  width: 850px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first-part">
    First part
  </div>
  <div id="second-part">
    <div class="text-in-second-part">Second part</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a border to the parent element to better understand

Comment: now you can see why the sticky is not behaving as you want

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to split `second-part` div into two divs: one for a sticky header and another for width.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#first-part {
  left: 105px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#second-part-header {
  position: sticky;
  left: 105px; /*works*/
  right: 105px; /*works*/
  width: 130px; 
  background-color: silver;
}
.second-part-content {
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first-part">
    First part
  </div>
  <div id="second-part-header">
    Second part
  </div>
   <div class="second-part-content"/> <!-- Second part content for width -->
</div>
```